# How to specify default page to display in Ant Design table?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Sorry in advance, i am new in Ant Design. Let's say i have a table with 27 rows. The table is configured to display 10 rows per page. So, there will be 3 pages. Sometime (for some reason), i want to display by default the page number 2 instead of 1.

Is there something like this?

```
<Table pagination={{pageSize: 10, defaultPage: 2}} >...</Table>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `defaultCurrent` to set default initial page number

```js
<Table pagination={{pageSize: 10, defaultCurrent: 2}} >...</Table>
```